# How to create file object in c# without saving to hard disk in C#

Tags: c#, io

I have two method Save() and Load() of different classes. Both method have overload of 'String' and "Stream".

Could someone tell me how to save the data from one class using the save method and load to different class without creating any temp file?

Comment: Research the `MemoryStream` class.

Comment: Yes, I had tried Memory Stream class. But Load method does not support Memory Stream object. It throws exception at runtime

Comment: If a method parameter is declared as type `Stream` then any type that inherits `Stream` is acceptable and `MemoryStream` inherits `Stream`. If an exception was thrown then it's because you did something wrong, either with the stream or with either or both of the methods.  Update your question to include the code you are using and the specifics of the issue you encountered, which is exactly what you should have done in the first place as that's what this site is for.

Comment: @jmcilhinney. My code works. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Memory-Mapped files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files) especially at the non-persisted files section.

> Non-persisted files are memory-mapped files that are not associated
>   with a file on a disk. When the last process has finished working with
>   the file, the data is lost and the file is reclaimed by garbage
>   collection. These files are suitable for creating shared memory for
>   inter-process communications (IPC).